# Why am I getting this error when I run a script?

Tags: internet-explorer, autohotkey

Sometimes  I get this error when running a script:

[image: screen shot]

This one says "access is denied" but it sometimes says something different, though the problem is always with

```
    While IE.readyState != 4 || IE.document.readyState != "complete" || IE.busy
        Sleep, 5
```

The intent of this code is to wait for the web page in internet explorer to finish loading. This is running with Internet Explorer 11.01

Also this is how `IE` is defined

```
IE := IEGetbyURL("stackoverflow.com/")

IEGetbyURL(URL) {   
    For pwb in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
        If (pwb.LocationURL = URL and InStr(pwb.FullName, "iexplore.exe") > 0)
        Return pwb
}
```

Comment: what kind of script?

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung autohotkey

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if it is how you pasted the code here, but it looks like you should just need to put it in parentheses, like this: While (x,y,z)